# Flutter PDF View Causing App to crash in Debug Mode

Tags: android, flutter, crash, pdf-viewer

I am getting this error when I try to open the pdf view in my flutter app and then it just crashes.

Can someone please explain what it means and how I can fix this?

**debug console**

```
W/NetworkRequest( 4232): No App Check token for request.
W/Gralloc4( 4232): allocator 3.x is not supported
D/com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore( 4232): Starting PdfiumAndroid 1.9.0
W/ame.app_name( 4232): Accessing hidden field Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;->descriptor:I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/jniPdfium( 4232): Init FPDF library
E/name.app_name( 4232): [SurfaceTexture-0-4232-0] attachToContext: invalid current EGLDisplay
E/flutter ( 4232): [ERROR:flutter/fml/platform/android/jni_util.cc(182)] java.lang.RuntimeException: Error during attachToGLContext (see logcat for details)
E/flutter ( 4232):  at android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.attachToGLContext(SurfaceTexture.java:295)
E/flutter ( 4232):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.renderer.SurfaceTextureWrapper.attachToGLContext(SurfaceTextureWrapper.java:57)
E/flutter ( 4232):
F/flutter ( 4232): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(1256)] Check failed: fml::jni::CheckException(env).
F/libc    ( 4232): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 4311 (1.raster), pid 4232 (name.app_name)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***

Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86_arm:11/..../release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
Timestamp: 2021-11-23 18:23:05+1300
pid: 4232, tid: 4311, name: 1.raster  >>> com.app_name  <<<
uid: 10161
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(1256)] Check failed: fml::jni::CheckException(env).
'
    eax 00000000  ebx 00001088  ecx 000010d7  edx 00000006
    edi f1fee81e  esi c6cb5330
    ebp f79d0b90  esp c6cb52d8  eip f79d0b99
backtrace:
      #00 pc 00000b99  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
      #01 pc 0005ad68  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (syscall+40) (BuildId: 6e3a0180fa6637b68c0d181c343e6806)
      #02 pc 00076511  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+209) (BuildId: 6e3a0180fa6637b68c0d181c343e6806)
      #03 pc 013b2cca  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #04 pc 013ebfdb  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #05 pc 013bee87  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #06 pc 013b1466  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #07 pc 013b126b  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #08 pc 013e42f4  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #09 pc 013e103a  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #10 pc 013e4664  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #11 pc 013e103a  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #12 pc 013e341a  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #13 pc 013e103a  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #14 pc 013e4664  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #15 pc 013e103a  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #16 pc 013e4664  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #17 pc 013e103a  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #18 pc 013e4664  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #19 pc 013e103a  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #20 pc 013e4664  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #21 pc 013e103a  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #22 pc 013e0fe9  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #23 pc 013e222e  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #24 pc 013d3203  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #25 pc 0143cbdb  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #26 pc 0143b559  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #27 pc 0143c243  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #28 pc 0143d46e  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #29 pc 013e640d  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #30 pc 0143ba42  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #31 pc 0143b736  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #32 pc 0144ba63  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #33 pc 013e9eff  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #34 pc 013ed19b  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #35 pc 013ed0b0  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #36 pc 013f519a  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #37 pc 013f51c8  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #38 pc 00019337  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::SimpleLooperCallback::handleEvent(int, int, void*)+39) (BuildId: ab4be013cda31e8c45d48aa23a89d0f8)
      #39 pc 0001a367  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+1127) (BuildId: ab4be013cda31e8c45d48aa23a89d0f8)
      #40 pc 00019e96  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+118) (BuildId: ab4be013cda31e8c45d48aa23a89d0f8)
      #41 pc 000133f5  /system/lib/libandroid.so (ALooper_pollOnce+101) (BuildId: f98006d4d736575082b552ff24b66f6c)
      #42 pc 013f50dd  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #43 pc 013ed05e  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #44 pc 013ecb86  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #45 pc 013f1fe1  /data/app/~~q7cHzyrPJddj62AUtjgLRA==/com.app_name-Tsb6y2hp4sFDLxXaOtAGRA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 377c5e66aa67adcab92a5ad8d132199dbb3dce1e)
      #46 pc 000e6974  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+100) (BuildId: 6e3a0180fa6637b68c0d181c343e6806)
      #47 pc 00078567  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+71) (BuildId: 6e3a0180fa6637b68c0d181c343e6806)
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

**P.S.** I am using debug mode on a *'Pixel 4 API 30'* emulator and that's where the crash is happening. I did some research online and most people had this issue when they were trying to build it in release mode but my issue is occurring in debug mode itself.

I also tried modifying *'android>app>build.gradle'* by including proguard rules but nothing seemed to work so I reverted that back. I am including those code snippets as well in case that might help.

**build.gradle**

Not sure if this info is required but also including my minSdkVersion & tagetSdkVersion as well

```
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
```

```
    buildTypes {
        // release {
        //     // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        //     // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        //     signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        // }
        // release {
        //     minifyEnabled true
        //     shrinkResources true
        //     proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        // }
        debug {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
           minifyEnabled false
           shrinkResources false
        //    useProguard true
        //    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        //    matchingFallbacks = ['debug']
       }
    }
```

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
#Flutter Wrapper
-keep class com.shockwave.** { *; }
-keep class org.xmlpull.** { *;}
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
-dontwarn io.flutter.embedding.**

## Gson rules
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapter, TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapter
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

# Prevent R8 from leaving Data object members always null
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}

## flutter_local_notification plugin rules
-keep class com.dexterous.** { *; }
```

Scaffold body of my pdfview.dart (The code here is correct because I am getting the values through. It is either the package or something else with my app settings that I feel is causing the crash)

```
),
                body: PDFView(
                  filePath: widget.pdf!.path,
                  // autoSpacing: false,
                  // swipeHorizontal: true,
                  // pageSnap: false,
                  // pageFling: false,
                  onRender: (pages) => setState(() => this.pages = pages!),
                  onViewCreated: (controller) =>
                      setState(() => this.controller = controller),
                  onPageChanged: (indexPage, _) =>
                      setState(() => this.indexPage = indexPage!),
                ),
              )
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
  #Pdf Viewing
  flutter_pdfview: ^1.2.1
```

Comment: I've also tested on my personal phone (Mi 9t pro) & Pixel 2 API 29 emulator as well. Both end up with same issue. I think there are some additional configurations that I need to do with my app which I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to lie if you try to run the app in debug mode in Visual Studio Code.

Build your app from the terminal using 'flutter run'. Weird but that seems to be the solution that works for me. Switching the version of the Flutter extension in code didn't fix the issue either so if you are facing the same problem as me, try running the app from the terminal.